# Transformar código para eval()

Tags: php

Eu queria transformar esse código para eval(), porque ele ta lendo somente os arquivos como html do data.php e os scripts php não.

```
// arquivo cujo conteúdo será enviado ao cliente
$dataFileName = 'data.php';

while ( true )
{
    $requestedTimestamp = isset ( $_GET [ 'timestamp' ] ) ? (int)$_GET [ 'timestamp' ] : null;
    // o PHP faz cache de operações "stat" do filesystem. Por isso, devemos limpar esse cache
    clearstatcache();
    $modifiedAt = filemtime( $dataFileName );

    if ( $requestedTimestamp == null || $modifiedAt > $requestedTimestamp )
    {
        $data = file_get_contents( $dataFileName );

        $arrData = array(
            'content' => $data,
            'timestamp' => $modifiedAt
        );

        $json = json_encode( $arrData );
        echo $json;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep( 2 );
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que você quer dizer com `transformar esse código para eval()`?

Comment: http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/ Olhe o ultimo comentario desse post você vai me entender melhor

Comment: A tag de abertura do esta como <? Ou <?php

Comment: A Tag de abertura esta como <?php

Comment: @LucasC.S, apartir desse .php vc quer fazer uma requisição ao `data.php` é essa sua dúvida? Tente deixar isso mais claro, para vc pode parecer óbvio mas para outros não.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que isso pode ajudar:

```
ob_start(); // Ativa o buffer de saída
include($dataFileName); // Inclui o arquivo dentro do buffer
$data = ob_get_contents(); // Copia o buffer para a variável $data
ob_end_clean(); // descarta o conteúdo do buffer sem fazer nenhuma alteração na página
```

Você basicamente executa o conteúdo do include e manda ele para uma variável sem que ele interfira no script atual.

Comment: Oi gabriel eu já revolvi o problema, vlw por a ajuda ai ;D

Answer (score 1):

Se vc quiser que `data.php` seja processado pelo servidor passe ele como uma url, para [file_get_contens()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/projeto/template.php');
```

Fiz um exemplo tentando simular o seu erro, crie dois arquivos o `processa.php` e o `template.php`

**template.php**

```
<h1>template</h1>
<?php
     $i=0;
    while($i < 11){
        echo $i .'<br>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

**processa.php**

Quando executado dessa forma a saida foi o html e o código php impresso na tela, ou seja não exibiu os valores de `$i`.

```
echo file_get_contents('template.php');
```

Quando colocado como uma url ele imprimiu os valores de `$i`

```
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/projeto/template.php');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Pra falar a verdade eu já tinha feito a mesma coisa só que não pego não sei porque :/

Comment: Mano agora ta pegando mas não atualiza os dados que ta sendo puxado do bando de dados

Comment: Cria um arquivo com um select pra você ver e inseri algo na tabela ele não atualiza só aparece quando da f5